# How to loop through two lists to create a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I want to create a **dictionary**, using the **degree** as a **key** and the values have to be all the students that take that degree. Below, sam takes bcom, jack take bcom, etc. Thanks in advance

```
students = ['sam','jack','rose','khan','marry','xio']
degrees = ['bcom','bcom','bsc','arts','bsc','arts']
```

Comment: This question and the following answers helped me with solving the issue of creating a dictionary from two lists. This question also shows a good example of what happens when there are common dictionary keys. +1 for the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this snippet do what you want:

```
dictionary = {}
for degree, student in zip(degrees, students):
    dictionary.setdefault(degree, []).append(student)
```

> {'arts': ['khan', 'xio'], 'bcom': ['sam', 'jack'], 'bsc': ['rose', 'marry']}

Answer (score 2):

Here is another compact way to achieve this behavior:

```
s2d = dict(zip(students, degrees))
{k: [s for s, d in s2d.items() if d==k] for k in degrees}
```

> {'bcom': ['sam', 'jack'], 'bsc': ['rose', 'marry'], 'arts': ['khan', 'xio']}

Although it won't work if you have if the same student will take two different degrees